# Error when clicking on an Item in Sitecore Backend

Tags: sitecore, backend, sitecore6

When I click on most Items in the Content Editor, I get the following error message:

[image]

It's a Sitecore 6.3 with SIP 3.2. How can I fix this?

Comment: Please copy and paste the error instead of just providing a screenshot. That way this can get picked up by Google and be easier to find for future readers with the same problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem may sometimes occur when the setting `DisableBrowserCaching` is set to `false`. Please visit [this Knowledge Base article](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/394385) for solutions.

Comment: @SpaceJump have you tried the second solution from the article?

Comment: Solution 2 seems to have fixed the problem. Thanks a lot!